# instance.invokeMethod memory leak

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, blazor

I am making lots of calls back to C# through .invokeMethod, and my GarbageCollector seems to be choking. Apparently I do not quite understand Javascript/Blazor interop memory management, so hopefully one of you can assist.

I am setting up window.requestAnimationFrame to call back to c#. The JS looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.anim = {
        start: function (instance) {
            console.log('start');
            return window.requestAnimationFrame(function (timestamp) { anim.callback(instance); });
        },

        callback: function (instance) {
            instance.invokeMethod('IncrementCount');
            var callbackId = window.requestAnimationFrame(function (timestamp) { anim.callback(instance); });

        },

        stop: function (callbackId) {
            window.cancelAnimationFrame(callbackId);
        }
    };

</script>
```

My Razor page looks as follows:

```
@page "/counter"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var dotNetReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("window.anim.start", dotNetReference);
        }
    }

    [JSInvokable("IncrementCount")]
    public void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;

        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

My GarbageCollector quite quickly comes up with "GC_MINOR: (Nursery full)" messages, and my System / JSArrayBufferData looks huge.
From the documentation, i can gather that objects should be disposed, but should they also in instances like this? (and where?!)

(Update: OK, so System / JSArrayBufferData is always huge, even when running the Blazor samples. So I guess that's not any indication on its own.. But that still doesn't help me)

The reason why this is a problem is that the GC VERY often kicks in as soon as I try to do anything meaningful. The example here is just to illustrate that it happens even in the simplest of cases.

Thanks!

/Thomas

Comment: You might have some luck limiting the scope of your ```IJSRuntime``` instance that DI is giving you. I'm thinking that inheriting from OwningComponentBase as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#utility-base-component-classes-to-manage-a-di-scope) would allow the JSRuntime instance to pass out of scope and flush more frequently. I could be wrong but it would be fairly simple to prototype and test.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Takes longer for the GC to react, but after 15.000 counts it still kicks in with the message... So it looks like taking out StateHasChanged() just slows it down?

Comment: @NikP Tried moving inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime; in to OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) (..that's what you meant, right?).

Didn't look as if it makes any diffirence.

Comment: Not quite. I'll list out what I mean in an answer below, though it might not work.

Answer (score 1):

This may not work and is being added as a more complete suggestion to the comment made on the original question. I would encourage the OP to comment on how effective this is, and also anyone else to correct me where I'm wrong so that I can learn more about this.

Due to the ``IJSRuntime``` filling up the memory, the thought behind this is that it's possible the the lifetime scope of the runtime is lasting far longer than it should, and since Blazor is a stateful framework the state is being carried along with it.

Something to try is to use `OwningComponentBase` to enforce the scope of the JS Runtime to the life of the component, intead of the life of the connection in Blazor Server or as a singleton in Blazor WASM. Set up should only take a few lines of code. At the top of the Razor file:

```cs
@inherits OwningComponentBase
```

and then in the @code block:

```cs
@code {

    // Property for the runtime, NOT injected here    
    public IJSRuntime Runtime { get; set; } 

    // Sets up the Runtime as a scoped service, so it will release and be available 
    // for Garbage Collection when the component is torn down
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Runtime = ScopedServices.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();
    }

}
```

If my thinking is correct, this *should* help with the memory management. I encourage others who may be more knowledgeable on the subject to comment on or edit this post as well.

This is following the [Official Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#utility-base-component-classes-to-manage-a-di-scope) regarding scoped service lifetimes in Blazor.

Hopefully this helps, please report back!

Comment: Thanks for a detailed response!  I implemented as suggested, but it doesn't immediately show any difference from what I saw before. GC still complains.

What I don't understand is what actually generates garbage here...

Answer (score -1):

So, after investigating some more, I am fairly sure that I am misinterpretation Mono GC messages for memory leaks.

It looks like there are no leaks after all, but that the GC is just letting you know that it is cleaning up. Apologies for the wild goose chase! :)

I am still concerned with the amount of information by the GC in the project that triggered this post (https://github.com/jackpotdk/BlazorGame), but I'll look more in to that.

Thanks.